# App using GStreamer doesn't work when another app is using ALSA

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, gstreamer, alsa

I am using Ubuntu 12.04, which of course uses ALSA for sound. I have two apps that I'm working with that use GStreamer to decode and play media, and whenever I am listening to Pandora or have Youtube running, my apps won't work.

For the one app, whenever it starts, it tries to set the pipeline state to playing and it gets an error that it can't. The other app gives me an error on the bus that gives me this information:

```
    Setting the pipeline to play. Playing.
    Error received from element autoaudiosink-actual-sink-alsa: Could not open audio device for playback. Device is being used by another application.
    Debugging information: gstalsasink.c(689): gst_alsasink_open (): /GstAlsaSink:autoaudiosink-actual-sink-alsa:
    Device 'default' is busy
```

I use autoaudiosink in the pipeline for both apps, so this output shows me that it's choosing ALSA for the audio sink. No surprise there. But, it also means that GStreamer is trying to horde ALSA all for itself and doesn't play nicely with other media apps. I did some testing and my theory seems to hold.

Can anyone tell me if there is a way to set up GStreamer audio on Ubuntu so it will work with other media applications? Or is it known that when using GStreamer audio, other media apps can't run?

Comment: Can you also try pulsesink other than autoaudiosink and tell us the results

Comment: I tried swapping out the autoaudiosink with pulsesink, and the pipeline didn't seem to link properly. The set up for the audio portion of my pipeline is queue -> a52dec -> ac3parse -> audioresample -> audioconvert -> pulsesink. Is this right?

Comment: Are you sure dec(oder) will come before parse(er). Can you please try switching them also. IMO, parser must be before decoder in the queue.

Comment: Woops, sorry, I actually do have the parser before the decoder. And I found the reason it wasn't working was because I didn't have the dependencies for pulse audio. I installed them and it works great! I can now have other media apps running at the same time as my apps. Thanks!

Comment: Though, in hopes that I can still use ALSA sink and for a more thorough answer, is there a way to set up GStreamer using ALSA sink that will allow other apps to play?

Comment: Check ps -ef | grep sound  or check grep alsa or check grep pulse and paste the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use `pulsesink` then try. You should also resolve all the required dependencies.

Comment: Replacing my autoaudiosink with pulsesink worked great! Thanks!

I would prefer to use alsasink though, and I still haven't found a way to fix the issue. So, if anyone knows how to fix this, please provide an answer.